# PHP process cloned inputs into coherent outputs

Tags: php, forms, post

I am using jquery-cloneya.min.js in my forms for the cloning of multiple input fields for example:

First Name  -  Last Name

I have this working almost perfectly. The fields are duplicated as expected and my form processing sends through the results using below:

Processor:

```
$tenenatfirstname = $_POST["tenenatfirstname"];
    if ($tenenatfirstname[0]!=""){
        $tenenatfirstnameeach = implode( ', ', $tenenatfirstname);
}
$tenenatlastname = $_POST["tenenatlastname"];
    if ($tenenatlastname[0]!=""){
        $tenenatlastnameeach = implode( ', ', $tenenatlastname);
}
```

Email handler:

```
Tenants first name: '.$tenenatfirstnameeach.'<br>
Tenants last name: '.$tenenatlastnameeach.'<br>
```

This spits out within the generated email:

```
Tenants first name: John, Michael, Sarah
Tenants last name: Jones, Smith, Camm
```

But as you can see all the first names are on one line and all the last names are split.

Is there anyway of binding these together so the last name corresponds to the correct first name such as:

```
Tenants name: John Jones, Michael Smith, Sarah Camm
```

I know I can simply turn the First Name field into Full Name however for my own skills building in PHP (as I am quite a beginner), I would love to find a way around this if it's possible.

Comment: Just a little bump here, curious if anyone has any options for me to try?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not concatenate them??  IE:

```
Tenants first name: '.$tenenatfirstnameeach.'<br>
Tenants last name: '.$tenenatlastnameeach.'<br>

Tenants full name: '.$tenenatfirstnameeach. ' ' .$tenenatlastnameeach.<br>
```

Comment: Hi Zac, apologies if I have missed something but I think that option falls down in regards to duplicating of the fields. Using jquery-cloneya.js allows you to select a series of form fields that are bound together, when the user needs to add multiple people in this case, the First Name and Last Name fields are duplicated as many times as the user requires providing multiple first name fields and multiple last name fields. I believe your option would generate Tenants full name: John, Michael, Sarah, Jones, Smith, Camm